# Browser support for stopImmediatePropagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

IE support for `stopPropagation()` is lacking, and [requires workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/387750/165673), but I can't tell if the same thing is true for `stopImmediatePropagation()`- is it safe for all browsers, or does it requires its own set of workarounds?

Comment: If you use jQuery and not plain JavaScript it should work fine in IE too.

Comment: By the way, stopImmediatePropagation seems to have poor support within some mobile browsers, mainly Android Firefox, iOS Chrome and iOS Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stopPropagation mentioned on the other answer is related to the method natively available on browser for the `event` object , while the `stopPropagation()` method of jQuery works fine in all browser (since it's a wrapper for the same task, taking into account the browser capabilities in which this method is run)

Comment: This answer does not mention stopImmediatePropagation, which is the subject of the question.

Comment: the answer is based on a wrong assumption that made OP ask about stopImmediatePropagation: he asked about it because of a wrong assumption on stopPropagation

Answer (score 17):

I was wondering for the browser support of JavaScript's `event.stopImmediatePropagation` as well, so I decided to test it by checking whether the following method exists:

```
Event.prototype.stopImmediatePropagation
```

It's supported on the following desktop browsers:

- Internet Explorer 9+
- Firefox 10+
- Chrome 6+
- Safari 5.0+
- Opera 15+ (Presto doesn't support `stopImmediatePropagation`)